# Can an element toggle effect depend on changes on many elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Be gentle folks as I'm new to JQuery but I'm trying to edit some existing code (written by someone else) which renders some HTML with SHOW/HIDE triggers using JQuery toggles.  It works fine but I now need to extend it so that a specific DIV is triggered based on the condition of 2 elements further up the page.  Currently it's doing this fine listening for a single element (ie. only one condition attribute).

My question is what's the best way to do this and get a single DIV to be toggled ON/OFF based on the input from *EITHER* of 2 elements further up the page?

========

This is the DIV section I want to toggle ON/OFF by changing the class to "optional-section-open" when triggered...

```
<div
  class="optional-section"
  data-condition="elementOne_input elementTwo_input"> 
...
```

This is the JQuery section that's there right now which sets up the toggle but the problem I have is that ONLY the 2nd trigger is being applied (ie. overwriting the 1st one)...

```
var dataConditionArray = this.$content.data('condition').split(" ");
    for (var index = 0; index<dataConditionArray.length; ++index) {
      this.$toggle = document.getElementById(dataConditionArray[index]);
      if (this.$toggle !== null) {
        this.$toggle = $(this.$toggle);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

==========

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
ForestSDMC

Comment: What is `this.$toggle` referring to? How is it used? You are setting `this.$toggle` to a single element, perhaps you want to make it an array...but that all depends on how it's used.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what was going on in the mind of whoever wrote the code. It makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thanks....using Chrome developer tools the "this" object is a ConditionalControl for the DIV I'm trying to toggle on/off. and the $toggle is actually listening to the correct input element further up the page waiting to change the DIV's toggleClass to "optional-section-open" as expected.

Comment: I don't really know what a ConditionalControl is, or how it uses its $toggle property. Does it have any documentation? What do you have to do to get it to "listen" to multiple elements?

Comment: Also, the question's title doesn't really match its specifics. You're asking about some particular "ConditionalControl" which you're using - you should update the question to reflect that.

Comment: There's a return in the code, implying a function. What does the rest of the function look like and how is it called?

Comment: Thanks all for the responses so far.  This is very difficult to describe without posting the code itself and I cannot disclose the source code for this project I'm afraid.  I appreciate it is confusing from the snippets I've given so far.

I simply want to know if input elements A and B can **BOTH** trigger JQuery behaviour for element C and if so what's the high-level method of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: The simple answer is "yes of course they can", but how exactly to do so remains a mystery.

Comment: So something should happen to the div, based on when something happens to elementOne_input or elementTwo_input? Like a keyup or click happens to either input, if that happens, you want to perform the same action to the div?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your if (the one before the toggle), you have to have all your conditions.

Also, you should track changes on all elements that "control" the visibility of your element.

#### Here is an example

```js
$('input').keyup( function() {

  var $d = $( 'div' );
  var $input_0 = $( 'input:eq(0)' );
  var $input_1 = $( 'input:eq(1)' );

  
  if( $input_0.val() && $input_1.val() )
  {
    $d.css('color', '#090').text('Both have text');
  } 
  else if( $input_0.val() || $input_1.val() ) 
  {
    $d.css('color', '#900').text('One has text');
  }
  else
  {
    $d.css('color', '#CCC').text('None has text');
  }
}).keyup();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Fille the text fields and notice the text below</p>

<input/><input/>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some dirty solution for you. You can take it from here and clean it up a little bit:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input id="r1" type="radio" name="someName" value="v1">v1</input><br>
    <input id="r2" type="radio" name="someName" value="v2">v2</input><br>
    <input id="r3" type="radio" name="someName" value="v3">v3</input>

    <div class="magick-div" data-condition="r1">Some div 1</div>
    <div class="magick-div" data-condition="r2">Some div 2</div>
    <div class="magick-div" data-condition="r3">Some div 3</div>

    <div class="magick-div" data-condition="r1 r2">Some div 1 2</div>
    <div class="magick-div" data-condition="r2 r3">Some div 2 3</div>
    <div class="magick-div" data-condition="r1 r3">Some div 1 3</div>

    <div class="magick-div" data-condition="r1 r2 r3">Some div 1 2 3</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var allRadios = [];

    $('.magick-div').each(function(){        
        var div = $(this);
        var conditionalRadioElements = div.attr('data-condition')
            .split(' ')
            .map(function(id){ return '#' + id})
            .map(function(selector) {return $(selector)});

        allRadios = allRadios.concat(conditionalRadioElements);

        conditionalRadioElements.forEach(function(radio){
            function update(){        
                var anyRadioSelected = conditionalRadioElements.map(function(radio){
                   return radio.is(':checked'); 
                }).reduce(function(acc, selected){
                    return acc || selected;
                });


                if(anyRadioSelected){
                    div.show();   
                }
                else {
                    div.hide();                    
                }
            }

            radio.change(function(){
                allRadios.forEach(function(radio){
                    radio.trigger('magick-update');    
                })
            });

            radio.on('magick-update', update);

            update();
        })
    })
})
```

JsFiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/fwukoj6m/5/

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, the reason your code is only doing the second trigger is because of the reassignment in your if statement.

It is hard to see what you mean by your example but is this of any use? (disclaimer I haven't tried this and just typed it up in the answer box so there may be typos)

```
//Should be a constant somewhere
var CLASS_OPTIONAL_SECTION_OPEN = "optional-section-open";

.....

var dataConditionArray = this.$content.data('condition').split(" ");
var conditionArraySize = dataConditionArray.length - 1;
for (var index = 0; index <= conditionArraySize; ++index) {
    var toggleElement = document.getElementById(dataConditionArray[index]);
    if (toggleElement){
        if (index === conditionArraySize){
            // assuming that this.$toggle refers to the jQuery object you wish to show?
            this.$toggle.toggleClass(CLASS_OPTIONAL_SECTION_OPEN); //or .addClass()
        }
    }else{
        break;  // or return false; depending on what the rest of the code expects
    } 
}
```